# How to set array of array in single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Following is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Beanie
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Cap
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Beanie with Logo
        )

)
```

I want this into a single array like set key and value of array.

```
array(
    [1]=>Beanie,
    [2]=>Cap,
    [1]=>Beanie with Logo,
)
```

Comment: You can't have different values on same key(1).

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/c4JCo).

You can do,

```
array_merge(...$arr);
```

Splat operator will expose to all the values of array internally, to flatten array.

> **Your expected output is not possible in any coding language with**
>   **arrays.**
>
> **Note**: Indexes are mean to be unique, don't issue over its uniqueness :)